# how to change image top to bottom by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i'm have ads code in jsfiddle:  [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pus8we7/)

How to change 2 ads to always show bottom when i'm scroll the page (or change Padding / margin bottom)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="adsl">
        <image alt='scoll1-2tieng' src='http://www.maydoduonghuyet.com.vn/uploads/partners/scoll1_2tieng.gif' width='120' height='300' />
    </div>
    <div class="adsr">
        <image alt='scoll2-hdsd' src='http://www.maydoduonghuyet.com.vn/uploads/partners/scoll2_hdsd.jpg' width='120' height='300' />
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var sidebar   = $(".adsl");
    var offset    = sidebar.offset();
    var topPadding = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
            });
        } else {
            sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });    
var sidebar2   = $(".adsr");
    var offset2    = sidebar2.offset();
    var topPadding2 = 15;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > offset.top) {
            sidebar2.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding2
            });
        } else {
            sidebar2.stop().animate({
                marginTop: 0
            });
        }
    });   
});
```

==Up date==

Thanks for all suppot and ideas. i'm done questions by ideas `position`
This is code easy: [Update](http://jsfiddle.net/6pus8we7/7/)

```
    <div class="wrapper morediv">
    <div class="adsl"><image alt='scoll1-2tieng' src='http://www.maydoduonghuyet.com.vn/uploads/partners/scoll1_2tieng.gif' width='120' height='300' /></div>
<div class="adsr"><image alt='scoll2-hdsd' src='http://www.maydoduonghuyet.com.vn/uploads/partners/scoll2_hdsd.jpg' width='120' height='300'  /></div>
</div>
```

and css only:

```
.wrapper{
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 1600px;
    position:relative;
    background: #FF0004
}

.adsl{
    position: fixed; margin-left: -135px; bottom: 0
}
.adsr{
    position: fixed; margin-left: 515px; bottom: 0
}
```

Thanks all

Comment: Always include the relevant code and markup __in__ the question, don't just link (not even to a fiddle). Links rot, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you.

Comment: you can set fixed position of ads.

Comment: @Satpal Thanks i'm insert carefully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `position:fixed;` if you have to always show the ads at the bottom

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pus8we7/2/)

```
.adsl img, .adsr img {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
}

.adsl img{
     left:0;  /* set image to left */
     z-index:90; 
}

.adsr img{
     right:0; /* set image to right */
    z-index:90;
}
```

Comment: but `position:fixed` make image to left+right bottom not closer wrapper

Comment: @HoangAn : ok...so you want the `image` at *bottom of screen* not *bottom of the page*?

Comment: now `<div class="adsl">& <div class="adsr">` is top. I want `<div class="adsl">& <div class="adsr">` to bottom page and closer `div wrapper`. This is ad scroll

Comment: @HoangAn : `bottom page` and `closer div wrapper`..not able to understand this part mate, i assume we are hitting a language issue! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep ads at the bottom but still animate them, change your JavaScript to this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var sidebar   = $(".adsl");
    var offset    = sidebar.offset();
    var topPadding = 10;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            sidebar.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + sidebar.height()/2 + topPadding
            });
    });    
    var sidebar2   = $(".adsr");
    var offset2    = sidebar2.offset();
    var topPadding2 = 10;
    $(window).scroll(function() {
            sidebar2.stop().animate({
                marginTop: $(window).scrollTop() + sidebar2.height()/2 + topPadding2
            });
    });

});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6pus8we7/6/)

---

Side note: The snippet above could be written just in couple of lines but I'm not sure if this effect is what the OP wants.

Comment: bang on..slight glitch though...it goes on infinite scrolling!!

Comment: @NoobEditor Not here! But is could check it.

Comment: @NoobEditor Speechless! I like friendly people :)

Comment: glad to meet you too fella!! :D